# Java: how can I react to computer shutdown in windows xp?

Tags: java, handler, shutdown

Is it possible make some handler that will do something when user shutdown computer with Java on Windows XP (optional, win7)? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to add a shutdown hook to your Java program which is invoked if the JVM is shutdown for any reason <strike>(other than `System.exit()`)</strike> including O/S shutdown.  Is that what you want?

Use: `java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)`:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // shutdown code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: iirc, at leats in Java 6, shutdown hooks still run even if System.exit() is called - the only time they are not is if the process is sent a kill command (or the OS equivalent)

Answer (score 4):

a shutdown hook should do the job.

From [API Doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)):

> Registers a new virtual-machine shutdown hook.
>   The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    // do something
  }
});
```